# Sublime Text 2 remapping keys

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text-2

I'm using sublime as my main text editor and I am remapping my arrow keys from the arrows to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>.

I have noticed that on Ubuntu 14.04 after I remap my keys that when I click <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> the menu at the top of sublime is now in focus and has a drop down opened up! The other 3 keys seem to work for moving the cursor.

I have tried to figure out how to disable the menu bar at the top of the screen from getting selected anytime <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> is pressed but I can't figure it out. I'm pretty sure it is an operating system problem as opposed to a sublime issue.

Can anyone shed a little light on the subject? I have already tried to disable the "activate the window menu" in keyboard shortcuts. It didn't seem to work on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution. The way to do it is to disable app menus from appearing and you can achieve this by doing these two commands:

sudo su; 
  echo "export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0" > /etc/X11/Xsession.d/81ubuntumenuproxy;

After these commands restart your computer.